meaning of "eyebrow home"
What does "eyebrow home" mean in this context football (soccer)?

GOAL! Fulham 1-2 Aston Villa (Watkins 59)
Youri Tielemans whips in a
corner, Ollie Watkins eyebrows home, and Andreas Pereira’s penalty
miss looks super-costly now.

Source: The Guardian

Maybe he heads the ball with his forehead (where his eyebrows are)? I can see a few uses, most of which are about players meeting a cross in front of the goal, in which case heading the ball is common.

Watkins scored for Aston Villa with a header https://youtu.be/GZMHIm8WkFw?si=_PtQqd1vK_La5ovW&t=93

@StuartF you should post an answer, I'm sure you know more about British football than I do! Include the other uses too, I didn't find any while searching, but I wasn't looking that hard.

@Mari-LouA - also 2 Dec 2014 GOAL! Manchester United 2-1 Stoke City A free kick out on the right, 30 yards out. Mata loops it into the box. And it flies into the top-left corner! Now then, Rojo races off celebrating, claiming he’d eyebrowed the ball onwards for the goal, rising from a central position ten yards out. If he did, that was offside... The Guardian

@MichaelHarvey It seems it is used two different ways.

The goal was scored by a header, with Watkins hitting the ball with the area above his eyebrows. "Eyebrow" here is used here as a verb, in the same way as some other body parts like "knee" or "elbow" to mean "to hit with [that body part]". To knee something [in] is to hit it with your knee, to elbow something [in] is to hit it with your elbow, and to eyebrow something [in] is to hit it with your eyebrows - this is a rather non-standard usage of "verbing" a body part that is not normally a verb.
"Home" here indicates the goal itself. The phrase "eyebrows home" describes the act of scoring a goal with a header.

Yes, sure a verb, but where did you see this? "After half-time, Watkins steered Villa in front with a near-post header, not long before Andersen was sent off for hauling the same player down deep in Fulham territory." I think that's the game, in fact. https://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/fulham-aston-villa-live-stream-premier-league-2024-b2632077.html?#post-1790317 Do you agree that is the game they're talking about here? Maybe you're right.

I posted a video clip of the header in the comments

I'd also add that the source (The Guardian's Minute-By-Minute report) is a live text commentary well-known for its writers' creative use of language for comic effect. This makes for a more interesting read.
